# How do we deallocate memory that has been allocated like this: A& o = *(new A)?

Tags: c++

Please, take a look at the program code down below. I have put plenty of comments to make it clear what it is that I'm having a problem with.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        void test() {
            std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    A& o = *(new A); // The memory for object "o" is allocated on the heap.
    o.test();        // This prints out the string "foo" on the screen.
                     // So far so good.

    // But how do I now deallocate the memory used by "o"? Obviously,
    // memory has been allocated, but I know of no way to relinquish it
    // back to the operating system.

    // delete o;     // Error: type ‘class A’ argument given to ‘delete’,
                     // expected pointer


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just avoid `new` with `A o;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line is weird

```
A& o = *(new A);
```

consider changing it. I don't see any advantage of just declaring it a pointer, `A* o = new A();`.

---

If you want to deallocate the memory:

```
delete &o; //Deletes the memory of 'o'
```

Note that if you had defined `o` as

```
A o = *(new A);
```

you would have *no* way of deallocating the memory, because then `o` would be a copy (with a totally new address!) of the `A` allocated. `o` would have been thus been created on the stack, and so `delete &o;` would result in undefined behavior.